# configurable mouse side buttons not working properly in gnome

Tags: gnome, mouse

I have a mouse with configurable side buttons. There is a windows software for the mouse that saves the configuration into the mouse itself, so I can configure it on windows and use it on Linux

I tested the mouse on Ubuntu Mate and Lubuntu and it worked as expected.

Unfortunately, there is an issue using gnome based distros (tried pop os 20.04 and ubuntu 19.10).

When I press the side button, the computer freezes for some seconds before the button works.

Have you ever seen this bug? Any idea to solve it?

The problem is not mapping side buttons, but freezing and lag when preesing the side buttons

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The issue occurred in Pop OS, Ubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie

The issue did not occur in:

- Pop OS (same instalation but with Mate desktop environment)
- Fedora with gnome
- Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Mate

Comment: Make and mdel of the mouse, please?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is related to whatever config or signals the windows setup thing is sending? Have you tried clearing the windows config in the mouse and then seeing if you get signals on the extra buttons (use `xev`) (without freezing/lag) and then configuring within Ubuntu using `xbindkeys`? I have configured extra mouse buttons this way. I can elaborate if required.